# Is it possible for a SE to create a Mouse Click picture with html handles, similar to <kbd> inputs?

Tags: feature-request

Being most active in AskUbuntu, I think some questions would benefit (given that we are often dealing with new computer users) with some icons like this:

[Left Click http://static.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/purple/mouse-right-click-32.png](http://static.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/purple/mouse-right-click-32.png)

Excuse my ignorance, but just as we have <kbd>keyboard button</kbd> functionality, would it be possible to implement something similar in accordance to mouse clicks? Would this be something that SE in general would be interested in?

Comment: If your new computer users don't know what a "right mouse button" is, hiding that terminology from them and replacing it with a cutesie graphic is only going to prolong the problem. Dumbing things down never helps in the long run.

Comment: @Akiva if the smart people don't explain things to the silly people, the silly people do not get to be smart people.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for your comment. I think you make a fair point, however don't you think that if we add some simple visual handles, that some individuals would be more willing to read an answer? Speaking from my own experience, and being very visually oriented myself; I often avoid reading through answers formatted as a wall of text. I can only imagine how this must feel to a new Computer User who may have a poor grasp on the English language. Although this is not the norm, would you agree in this usecase scenario, this may be helpful? I look forward to your response.

Comment: @Akiva: Anyone who struggles reading a lot of text is not going to do particularly well in this field, and perhaps it's best they discover that now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for your followup. Unfortunately, I regard your answer as a Red Herring, as you did not answer my question. To your statement though; Stack Exchange Websites could not meaningfully be regarded as one field, in that they are designed to provide answers and facilitate questions for any field. To wit; Ubuntu is a field which aims for accessibility for all people, from the disabled, to the elderly, to the third world. I think it is inappropriate therefore to hold them up to what I presume to be, very high standards for yourself. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, sorry if you thought it was a "red herring". In case you couldn't read between the lines, then, here is my answer in dumbed-down form: "no".

Comment: The broader discussion aside of whether this is a good move for society, I don't see any particular reason _not_ to add these icons. However, I also don't see it happening. You need strong reasons to make changes and add functionality, not strong reasons to avoid them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_calling ; to your answer though, "no", I take it to mean you believe that a person with a poor grasp on computer vernacular and then English language would not benefit from simple visual cues (As that was my question). I would imagine in order to be consistent with that principle, you would also have to conclude that no one benefits from the Keyboard button html handles. Is this true, or did I misinterpret you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To your statement about needing strong reasons to make changes; I agree; I think that is a reasonable statement. However from my own experience in development, after a product reaches a certain maturity, all the features which had big reasons to implement them, have been implemented, and all that is left are small features. If SE reaches that juncture, I think it is perfectly reasonable to add an admittedly small feature. What do you think?

Comment: @Akiva: I would agree with that. However SE has a _long_ way to go until that is the case. :)